# Vue.js & airbnb no-param-reassign lint rule - How to modify properties in array of objects?

Tags: vuejs2, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm using vue-cli & accepted the ESLint default rules including `no-param-reassign` which I've never used before.

I have a method that needs to:

1. accept an array of `columnDefinition` objects
2. Iterate through the objects and assign each one a `columnDefinition.originalOrder` number
3. Reorder & return the array.

`no-param-reassign` keeps erroring unless I use lodash to create a new array of new objects and return that.

So for example, I pass in

```
                [
                    {
                        label: 'Number of Siblings',
                        searchEnabled: false,
                        sortEnabled: false,
                        newOrder: 3,
                        lotsOfNestedData: {
                            moreNesting: 'etc',
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Pet Name',
                        searchEnabled: false,
                        sortEnabled: false,
                        newOrder: 1,
                        lotsOfNestedData: {
                            moreNesting: 'etc',
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Favorite Hobby',
                        searchEnabled: false,
                        sortEnabled: false,
                        newOrder: 4,
                        lotsOfNestedData: {
                            moreNesting: 'etc',
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Favorite Outfit',
                        searchEnabled: false,
                        sortEnabled: false,
                        newOrder: 2,
                        lotsOfNestedData: {
                            moreNesting: 'etc',
                        },
                    },
                ]
```

Without this rule, I would `.each` through the array and mutate objects with a `item.originalOrder = idx` property. Then mutate the array with `.sort` based on `newOrder`.

With the no mutating params rule, the best I can think of is to create a new array (so that I can sort it) and then create clones of each object which I can then add the `.originalOrder` property to.

```
const newSrcArray = _.map(srcArray, (item, idx) => {
    const newItem = _.cloneDeep(item);
    newItem.originalOrder = idx;
    return newItem;
});

//sort newSrcArray

return newSrcArray;
```

This looks like extra code and memory, but am I missing something entirely?

Is this boilerplate/memory the preferred way to do this?

Or is the best practice just to turn the rule off?

Comment: could you provide some array data and precise what you want

Comment: Hi boussadjra, I updated it. Thank you!

Comment: do you have the sort algorithm ?

Comment: I asked the question on the [vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-no-param-reassign-a-best-practice-in-vue/45940) and got an answer back from a vue leader: "I personally don’t like that preset very much as it is far too strict for my taste, but that’s up to everyone’s tastes. The Vue project itself doesn’t have an opinion about it."

Comment: It's a personal opinion but why don't you accept my answer? what went wrong with it ?

Comment: I appreciate the coding replacing lodash, but the question was what is the vue-approved best practice approach, and I didn't think your answer was as definitive as the new information documented from the vue team

Comment: I'm actually not sure why the documented answer got switched to a comment. Apologies to people looking for the official answer

Comment: ok i will delete my answer , i wasted my time for nothing :(

Comment: Sorry. It was helpful. And I appreciate the work. I just thought the official vue answer on framework opinion was the best answer :(

Comment: i undeleted it, maybe it would help someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an official answer now on the vue.js [vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-no-param-reassign-a-best-practice-in-vue/45940)

"The Vue project itself doesn’t have an opinion about it."

So the answer to the original question is option 2: it is not a Vue best practice to leave the no-param-reassign rule on.